# css: max-width doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have a question about css: `max-width` for html div tags (.sidenav and .right_nav) that don't function like .header and .footer. As we know with max-width css property the html elements maximizes until the max-width value, but when we narrow dimensions the html elements respond responsive. In this case the .sidenav and .right_nav are the div tags that don't function like that. Here is the code on JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmxmahev/6/)

Comment: How is it not working? It seems to be working fine in the fiddle from what I can see.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It's working fine. What is your exact question?

Comment: The sidenav and right_nav don't respond to max-width, that is the problem

Comment: You should probably add more details... but if you have divs side-by-side with no content they don't have a width based on max-width. Max-width is just that, the widest you want the div to be. So for example if you gave it `width: 100%; max-width: 900px` it would make the div 100% the width of it's parent element, maxing out at 900px.

Comment: @chrislebaron, In this case it can be maximized for example to 900px max-width, but its not responsive smaller than that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `width: calc(100% - 20px)` to .sidenav and .right_nav. That is all.

You should tell the divs to be 100% width, but not wider than the amount of pixels specified in max-width. Max-width does not automatically assume it can take all available space. That is why you need to add the `width: calc(100% - 20px)` statement.

Fixed it here: https://jsfiddle.net/d1L53sqe/

Comment: You are right that the .sidenav and .rigth_nav will maximize but why they don't response smaller when the divs are narrowed

Comment: Now with width: calc(100% - 20px); property works ok, but I have to add a small correction: width: calc(100% - 22px);. This correction must be like thit because when the .sidenav and .right_nav came narrowed until the end thez are not in the same right line with the header and footer.

Comment: Thanks, but I also added `box-sizing: border-box;`. Did you take that into account?

Answer (score 3):

just add :

```css
box-sizing: border-box;
```

and it will be work fine :)

Comment: Please a few words explaining how this works.

Comment: The box-sizing property is used to tell the browser what the sizing properties (width and height) should include.

Comment: Very nice answer.